# Activity Indicator continues to spin

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

If you open the app when you are not connected to any network, it displays the questions that were last retrieved. If you click on any question, it displays the error on top 'Request Failed. Tap to Retry' which is fine as it detects that the request failed due to no network. But the activity indicator does not stop spinning.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm in 0.1.54 while in airplane mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for catching this. I've also made similar fixes on the activity indicator on the answers side.

This will be fixed in version **0.1.57.**